# Java Play! Framework - Unable to populate form with existing value

Tags: playframework-2.3

I am using Java Play framework 2.3.6  .I can't able to populate the form  with existing value.

Given below the code snippets.

Application.java

```
 public class Application extends Controller{
    static Form<Roles> rolesForm=Form.form(Roles.class);

    public static Result getRoleById(Long id){
    Roles r = RolesDao.getRoleById(id);

    //rolesForm.fill(RolesDao.getRoleById(id));
    rolesForm.fill(r);
    return ok(updateRole.render(rolesForm));
}}
```

updateRole.scala

```
  @(roleForm : Form[models.Roles])
  @import helper._

@main("Update Role Details"){
   @form(routes.Application.updateRole(Long Id)){   
      @inputText(roleForm("role_short_description"))
      @inputText(roleForm("role_long_description"))
      @inputRadioGroup(roleForm("active_yn"))
    <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Update">
  }
 }
```

Roles.java

```
 public class Roles extends Model{
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(schema=Roles.SCHEMA,name="gen",     sequenceName="role_id_seq",allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="gen")
    public Long role_id;

    @Required
    public String role_short_description=null;

    @Required
    public String role_long_description=null;

    public String active_yn=null;
```

RolesDAO.java

```
public class RolesDao {

     public static Finder<Long,Roles> find = new Finder<Long, Roles>(
        Long.class, Roles.class
      );
     public static Roles getRoleById(Long id) {
        return find.where().eq("role_id", id).findUnique();
    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
public class Application extends Controller{

    public static Result getRoleById(Long id){

        Roles role = RolesDao.getRoleById(id);
        Form<Roles> rolesForm = Form.form(Roles.class).fill(role);

        return ok(updateRole.render(rolesForm));
    }
}
```

Always keep the form inside Action method rather than keeping it globally.

Comment: @Sivakumar Why should the form actions be present inside methods? Do you have any reason?